# Contacts from removed Google account still appear in Phone app - Android 9

Tags: 9.0-pie, android-one

I am currently using a Xiaomi Mi A2 (andoid one) with Android 9. 
At some point I added another google account to the phone, just to view some mails. 
After removing this account, the contacts saved to it were removed from the Contacts app, but still appear in the Phone app.
I have tried force stopping the Phone app, and clearing the cashe and the storage and also resetting the permissions.
Does anyone know what I can do?
Is there a way to find out if any contacts are stored in the internal storage do that I can mass delete them?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, moments after I posted this I found the answer and I am posting it in case someone else struggles for some days like I did. I went to the Contacts app, and on the menu I selected All contacts. This way everything appeared and I could just select all that I didn't need and delete them.